# Can I measure the click through rate (CTR) of a link to a phone number embedded in an email or SMS?

Tags: email, ctr, phone-number

I want to capture the CTR for the phone number provided in the mail that I send. Can I track that?

Somebody told me that we can only track CTR if there is a landing page on the CTA. Clicking on the phone number sends the user directly to the dialer and there's no landing link.

Comment: Have you looked into call forwarding tracking?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to track link clicks in emails without directing the user to a landing page on your website first. You can get open and basic analytical data from the email using Google Analytics Measurement Protocol but this only works by adding a hidden image to the email so only captures opens and client information but can not track link clicks where the user is not directed to a landing page first.

The most common method of doing this would be to add a contact us link to your email which directs to a landing page on your website and provides the end user the tel link on your landing page instead. By using the landing page you can use Google Analytics to track the link click without any problems.